# Vue,.js not rendering in .vue file

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-sfc

I'm trying to render Vue data in my `Summary.vue` file.

Here is my HTML: (index.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./lib/animate/animate.css">
</head>

<body>
  <app></app>
  <script src="./lib/jquery/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./src/summary-components.js"></script>
  <script src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

The 'app' tag is somehow connected with this file: (entry.js)

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './Summary.vue';

new Vue({
  el: 'body',
  data: {
    message: 'test',
  },
  components: { App },
});
```

Which finally renders my .vue file `Summary.vue`.
But my data won't render to my http server, even trying to use script tags. (Summary.vue)

```
<div id="summarye">{{ message }}</div>

<script>

  new Vue({
    el: '#summarye',
    data: {
      message: "Vue JS Testing"
    }
  });

</script>
```

In my 'summary-components.js' file i've tried:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import summary from './Summary.vue';
```

It's just not displaying. Can someone help me correctly import and get vue working?

Comment: How are you getting started? If I were you I'd install [vue-cli](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli) and start based off the code that gives you. It's very hard to follow what you're trying to do. A .vue file should look very different from that.

Comment: I think it's working like this: (Entry.js -> index.html). The index.html is rendering the .vue template.

Comment: im pretty sure you need to use webpack to import .vue files. and if you are using webpack your css and js import should be done in your main.js or app.vue. i second what @BillCriswell said and use a vue-cli template